# trying to use atoi and its not working

Tags: c

these are the errors i am getting:

```
    search.c: In function ‘checkGrades’:
    search.c:63: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from 
    integer without a cast
    /usr/include/stdlib.h:148: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is 
    of type ‘char’
    search.c:63: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
```

Here is my code:

```
    int checkGrades(STUDENT grades[], int maxrecs, FILE* fp)
    {
    char line[LINE_MAX];
    int rc;
    int count = 0;
    int score;
    char id;
    while(fgets(line,LINE_MAX, fp) != NULL)
    {
    rc = sscanf(line,
    "%25[^:]%*c%25[^:]%*c%6s%*c%3d%*c%3d%*c%3d%*c%3d%*c%3d%*c%2c",
                 grades[count].id,
                &grades[count].score[1],
                &grades[count].score[2],
                &grades[count].score[3],
                &grades[count].grade);
    if((rc != 9) ||

                    rc == atoi (id);

                 grades[count].id < 100000 ||
                 grades[count].id > 999999 ||
                 grades[count].grade < 0 ||
                 grades[count].grade > 110)
    {


            printf("Invalid Record: %s", line);
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
        if(count == TNARRAY_MAX)break;
    }
    printf("ID: ", grades-> id);
    }
```

Im not really sure if rc is what im supposed to be using for atoi, im a beginner in C and ive tried many combos with no success.  I know I need to convert the string to an int before comparing but im pretty lost here on how to do that.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first argument of `atoi` is supposed to be a string, which is `char*`. `id` is a `char`, not `char*`.

Comment: You also never set `id`.

Comment: `if((rc != 9) ||` is missing another condition after `||`.

Comment: "not really sure if rc is what im supposed to be using for atoi". That's what the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) is there for. It tells you what you are supposed to pass to the function.

Comment: i asked my professor about this and he said i needed to use atoi before comparing to "100000" thats why the atoi is where it is and the rest of the conditions follow. should i make the atoi before the if or after the rest of the conditions

Comment: Once again, you are applying `atoi` to a variable that contains garbage. Regardless of what your professor told you, there's no excuse for applying it to an uninitialized variable. What was the intent?

Comment: Also, you tell `sscanf` there are 9 variables to match, but you only supply 5.

Answer (score 1):

The atoi function expects a single pointer to a const string, like this: (const char *str)

You can see an example of its usage here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm

Also I'm not sure you meant to copy your entire code(I assume LINE_MAX and TNARRAY_MAX are macros defined somewhere?) but as it stands you have a curly brace mismatch, meaning this section of code as you've posted it needs one more '}' at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use atoi on a single character.  What you can do instead is to cast the character to an integer, and then subtract the ASCII value of the character '0' from it.

```
int num;

num = (int)id - (int)'0';
```

Also, as pointed out in the comments about, you don't actually initialize id.